# Cannot import machine module on MicroPython

Tags: python, esp8266, micropython

When using an ESP8266 and sending files to the board via the WebRepl I can use the machine module when typing directly into the console. However, when I send a Python script that imports the machine module to the board and import it to the console and run the method the code that uses the module doesn't run. I can access other modules and run other code that I have sent onto the board. Also when writing the Python script importing the machine module appears as an error.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong when importing the `machine` module from MicroPython?

```py
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep
led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
for n in range(1,30):
    led.on()
    sleep(1)
    led.off()
```

Comment: Can you show your code and the error output (if any)?

Comment: @Dschoni I have added the code to the post. I am just testing out a simple program on an ESP8266 and i can do it directly in the WebRepl but not if I send the file onto the board

Comment: There is an extra whitespace at the beginning of the second line. Python is not whitespace tolerant.

Comment: @Dschoni Thanks for spotting that but that is not it i have amended that and tried again but it appears that it is to do with the machine module. It appears as an error in my text editor which is VSCode and i can run other python scripts that i have sent to my ESP8266

Comment: *It appears as an error in my text editor* is not the same as *Cannot import machine module on MicroPython*. Can you please describe the exact problem, and paste exact error messages you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code, which most of the time will work on the MicroPython console on the esp8266. I have found in the programs I have written for the esp8266, I have had to import machine and then import time.

```
import machine
import time
LED4.Pin(4, machine.Pin.OUT, value=0)
```

That should run, and set the value of Pin 4 to 0 or low. You'll notice I didn't use the from machine import Pin.

In my experience, if you run it as

```
from machine import Pin
```

The program will not work correctly, I don't recall the error, just that it didn't run.

Secondly, the error will occur if the flash isn't working. You think it is flashed, but erroneous errors like this will happen. Use the esptool install to flash the esp8266 with the latest stable MicroPython and it should resolve the errors if the above does not work. I have had both instances work for me.

Answer (score 1):

it works like this (ESP8266, Nodemcu):

```
from machine import Pin
from utime import sleep
led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT) #GPIO2/D4
for n in range(1,30):
    led.value(0) #on
    sleep(1)
    led.value(1) #off
    sleep(1)
```

beware:

**led.value(0)** is turning led on,
**led.value(1)** then off,
**from utime import sleep** becouse it's micropython not python,
you also had bad looping formula, **sleep(1)** was added by me at end

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're trying to **run your program on micropython board and not on your pc**. If you're using Thonny Python IDE go to Run > Select interpreter. Then chose micropython (ESP8266) and proper port.