# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine'

Tags: python, python-3.x, esp32, micropython

when I try to control my esp32 microcontorller with micropython I get the following error:

```
  File "c:/Users/supre/Documents/Python Programme/micropython/blinktest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from machine import Pin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine'
```

I try to test the basic blinktest code:

```
from machine import Pin
import time

led = Pin(12, Pin.OUT)
for n in range(1,30):
    led.value(0) #on
    sleep(1)
    led.value(1) #off
    sleep(1)
```

I can't install this module via pip or anaconda
(when I try to install the module via pip the build fails)

Is this error maybe caused because I have installed micropython the wrong way?

So it would be very nice if someone could help me out with this problem.

Comment: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/packages.html suggests to use `upip` - how did you install the machine package? What error did you get?

Comment: Firsteful thank you very very much for your answer:) I tried to install the package via the normal pip. I think the error is to long to post in the comment section.

Comment: @Scripter1 please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635347/cannot-import-machine-module-on-micropython, and also you can try to create separate env to install pip packages.

Comment: Thanks @Anup I've already fixed it:)

Answer (score 5):

It appears you are attempting to run the `blinktest.py` on your PC , rather than on your ESP32 microcontroller.
the giveaway is that the `machine` module cannot be found which is part of the ESP32 firmware that should be installed on the ESP32.

you would need to :

- install/flash the MicroPython firmware on your ESP32
- transfer/copy `blinktest.py` to your ESp32
- connect to the ESP32 MicroPython repl
- then start `blinktest.py` by executing `import blinktest`

for a detailed step by step for the ESP32: http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/tutorial/intro.html#esp32-intro

Comment: When I use Pycharm with Micropython plugin, i have to be in micropython window instead of Python Console